# How to disable "New tablet mode for 2-in-1 convertible" of Windows 10 2004

Tags: windows, windows-10-v2004

Windows 10 version 2004 came with a new mode for 2-in-1 (**it's not tablet mode**, it's a mix). It's on when you put the keyboard facing backwards.

The problem it's that I like to use that way my notebook all the time, when plugged to my external monitors, external keyboard and mouse.

I can't find a way to disable it

[This article describes the new mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-insider/at-work-pro/wip-4-biz-whats-new#new-tablet-experience-for-2-in-1-convertible-pcs-build-18970)
[image]

[image]

I repeat: It's not tablet mode, I have tablet mode turned off
[image]

Comment: I spent some time looking at this and do not have anything different in terms of settings.  (1) Call the computer manufacturer's support line.  (2) If using a Microsoft Account, verify the settings of another computer with the same Microsoft Account. (These settings can sync across computers)

Comment: @John: (2) The setting it's ok, I just want to turn it off. (1) Will try with Dell if nothing happens

Comment: The new convertible mode should only be active when there isn't a external keyboard.  I suspect this is a driver problem.

Comment: Unfortunately version 2004 is not yet generally out, so few people can really test a solution. For example, does the following help: *Settings > System > Tablet mode*, and toggle to off "Make Windows more touch-friendly . . .".

Comment: @harrymc: As I stated in the question, Tablet Mode it's not the problem.

Comment: I finally don't understand your question. Do you want Tablet Mode to be enabled or disabled? In which mode you would like to work and when is it triggered?

Comment: You should give a look to [this other document-build 1952.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-insider/at-home/active-dev-branch): *In order to help ensure quality, the feature will be rolling out slowly, starting with a portion of the Insiders that have never detached their keyboard before, or have their tablet mode settings set to **Don’t ask me and don’t switch**.* Now it seems you should to do the opposite (or not to be in this condition): tablet mode on and ask me to switch. Try it and let us know. Good Luck `:-)`

Comment: _*Note: This feature was previously rolled out as an experiment to Windows Insiders in 20H1 Build 18970 and ended in Build 19013. After some refinement, we’re reintroducing it to Windows Insiders in this build and plan to deliver this experience to customers in a future Windows 10 update._ [From](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2020/03/25/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-19592/)

Comment: It is [reported](https://in.mashable.com/tech/6317/microsofts-testing-a-new-tablet-experience-for-2-in-1-convertible-pcs) that MicroSoft states tha it should be possible to set this behaviour from the options...but it seems they take a decision for you, even letting you should be able somehow to overcome it.

Comment: I thought it might work for it as fix although I knew your problem.Sorry remove down-vote if you can kindly @Eduardo Molteni

Comment: Thanks but anyway tell if its possible to remove down-vote on my post or I un-delete post to remove if necessary

Comment: You have downvoted everyone who tried to help, driving everybody off, instead of working with us in a cooperative effort to find a solution. Not very wisely done and no solution.

Comment: @harrymc: I've downvoted because they wasn't the right answer, I don't want to anyone to tried a solution that A. It's not correct B. Has been told several times that have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Cooperating with us gives much better results than downvote. FYI.